# Formula for flux accross a plane curve.

Tags: vector-analysis

If $\vec{r}(t) = x(t) i + y(t) j$ be a simple curve C in the domain of a continuous vector field $\vec{F} = F_1 i + F_2 j + F_3 k$. If $\hat{n}$ is the outward pointing unit normal vector to the curve C then the flux accross the plane curve C is given by 
$= \int_{C} \vec{F} . \hat{n} dS$

Now if is given in my book that

$\hat{n} = \hat{T} \times \hat{k}$ ( if curve is moving in counter clockwise direction)

And

$\hat{n} = \hat{k} \times \hat{T}$ (if curve is moving in clockwise direction)

$( \hat{T}$ is unit tangent vector to the curve$.)$

I didn't understand the direction of $\hat{n}$. I know, it is a unit vector normal to the curve, but why it is represented by cross product of $\hat{T}$ and $\hat{k} ?$

Comment: I dont' have your book. But most likely the north vector in this case is pointing outward *normal* to $T$ (and $k$)

Comment: It seems that $\hat n$ is the unit outward normal vector to the curve in $xy$ plane

Comment: $\hat{n} = \hat{T} \times \hat{k}$ represents $\hat{n}$ is normal to $\hat{k}$, but k is already normal to $xy$ plane !

Comment: Since $\hat{n}$ lies in the $xy-$plane, it's orthogonal to $\hat{k}$ and of course it's orthogonal to $T,$ so it's $\pm\hat{k}\times T$